# How do you create a Snackbar in Native Android with a Flutter View

Tags: android, flutter, view, android-snackbar, flutter-method-channel

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a Snackbar in my Flutter app with Native Android code. However to create a Snackbar with Native Android, you need to obtain a view (due to the parameters of creating a snackbar requiring a view) which I cannot since my Native Android code does not inflate an activity layout (it uses a background service instead).

So essentially, how would I create a Snackbar (in other words retrieve a flutter view) whilst in my Native Android code?

Or in other words, how would I create a Snackbar in my flutter app through my Native Android background service?

**My Attempts at a solution:**

I could use getFlutterView() using the

> import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity

however the plugins are not being generated with this import. Rather I'm using the

> import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

which seems to be the only way I could use generated plugins with Java (as I'm not programming in Kotlin) and this import doesn't seem to have the "getFlutterView()" feature.

Comment: Hi, did you found any implementation for this?

Comment: @baricoronel no not yet, I had to reroute my business logic around this problem.